# Need help in understanding the concept of run() while using interface in Java

Tags: java, interface

I am trying to learn the concept of the interface in Java. I have two .java files :

```
// I.java
public interface I {
    public abstract void run(double avg);
}

// S.java
public class S 
{
    public void func1(I ii, double av) 
    {
        System.out.println("Initial Average : " + av);
    }

    public void start() 
    { 
        double avg = 90;         // need to pass this avg to run()
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        S obj = new S(); 
        obj.func1(new I() {            // Please help in understanding this line also
            public void run(double avgg) {
                System.out.println("Final Average : " + avgg);
            }
        }, 76.8);
        obj.start();
    }
}
```

Output of Above Code :  Initial Average : 76.8

And The required output is this :

Initial Average : 76.8

Final Average : 90

Now, I am trying to understand the concept of run() in an interface, but I am not able to understand it. I want to understand the code of the main() so that I could modify it to get the required output. Means, How can we call the run() of the main() from start() and pass the value of avg = 90 for getting the required output.

Note : This is an assignment problem. But I am trying my best to understand the concept of run() in an interface ( which is used here). Also, I want to understand the complete code of main().

Comment: the second line of the main method creates an object that is a subtype of I (read up on anonymous inner classes) and passes it into the call to func1. then you don't do anything with it.

Comment: @NathanHughes, How can we call the run() of the main() from start() and pass the value of avg = 90 for getting the required output ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what purpose that solves but you can do something like this. (I have answered after reading the second comment. The first comment does answer the initial query.)

```
interface I {
    public abstract void run(double avg);
}

// S.java
public class S {

    I ii;

    public void func1(I ii, double av) {
        System.out.println("Initial Average : " + av);
        this.ii = ii;
    }

    public void start() {
        double avg = 90; // need to pass this avg to run()
        ii.run(avg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        S obj = new S();
        obj.func1(new I() { // Please help in understanding this line also
            public void run(double avgg) {
                System.out.println("Final Average : " + avgg);
            }
        }, 76.8);
        obj.start();        
    }
}
```